# Cannot GET :id route findById() express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, routes

I cannot `GET` data (with Insomnia) from my collection with an specific `id`. Below is an example request URL.

`http://localhost:5000/todos/5dd295a49d5d7a0b7a399bbe`

But when I http://localhost:5000/todos/. without the `id` I can display all the data inside the collection.

Here is my code :

- Todos route :

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Todo = require('../models/todo.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  Todo.find()
    .then(todos => res.json(todos))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const description = req.body.description;
  const date = Date.parse(req.body.date);

  const newTodo = new Todo({
    title,
    description,
    date
  });

  router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
    Todo.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(todo => res.json(todo))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('The fuck is the Error: ' + err));
  });

  router.route('/:id').delete((req, res) => {
    Todo.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
      .then(() => res.json('Todo deleted.'))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });

  router.route('/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
    Todo.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(todo => {
        todo.username = req.body.username;
        todo.description = req.body.description;
        todo.duration = Number(req.body.duration);
        todo.date = Date.parse(req.body.date);

        todo.save()
          .then(() => res.json('Todo updated!'))
          .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });

  newTodo.save()
    .then(() => res.json('Todo added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

- server.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose') // connect to mongoDATABASE

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(
    uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
} // always put those
);

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

const todosRouter = require('./routes/todos');

app.use('/todos', todosRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Are you able to `console.log(req.params.id)`?

Comment: I tried but I don't know where I can check the console.log

Comment: You can see it in the terminal/command line that your server is running on. Are you also able to perform the other actions that require an `id`? Such as delete and update?

Comment: There is nothing displayed about the console.log where the server is running, and other actions like update & delete do not work aswell

Comment: See Klaycon's answer. You're defining your `/:id` route within your `/add` route.

Answer (score 1):

I had an analogous situation. In my route file one of my GET routes was triggering **"Cannot GET" error**.  Another possible solution is just to place **all the GET Requests** **in one place** and THEN all the POST Requests (order matters). In my case that improved the situation and the error disappeared.

```
router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
   Todo.find()
   .then(todos => res.json(todos))
   .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

After comes the GET REQUEST, instead of The POST one.

```
  router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
  Todo.findById(req.params.id)
  .then(todo => res.json(todo))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('The fuck is the Error: ' + err));
});
```

So, basically FindByID was not causing the problem, but the order of the Requests. Hope somebody may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/:id` route setup is located within the callback of your `/add` route. Move them to the same scope as your other route setup and it should work as expected.

Comment: Ok I understand, but newTodo.save() where it should be ? outside the add or inside something ?

Comment: `newTodo.save()` can only be where `newTodo` is defined. I would guess it would simply go after you define `newTodo`.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I can see more clearly now. I hope this answer can help other beginner like me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `})` at the end of your `/add` route so the other routes are not defined within `/add`. Then do `newTodo.save()...` At the end of it. Then remove one `})` before `module.exports = router;`. See below.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let Todo = require('../models/todo.model');

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  Todo.find()
    .then(todos => res.json(todos))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const description = req.body.description;
  const date = Date.parse(req.body.date);

  const newTodo = new Todo({
    title,
    description,
    date
  });

newTodo.save()
    .then(() => res.json('Todo added!'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
})

  router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
    Todo.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(todo => res.json(todo))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('The fuck is the Error: ' + err));
  });

  router.route('/:id').delete((req, res) => {
    Todo.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
      .then(() => res.json('Todo deleted.'))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });

  router.route('/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
    Todo.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(todo => {
        todo.username = req.body.username;
        todo.description = req.body.description;
        todo.duration = Number(req.body.duration);
        todo.date = Date.parse(req.body.date);

        todo.save()
          .then(() => res.json('Todo updated!'))
          .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This will cause an error as there is an extra `});` now just before the export line. No brackets need to be added, just moved.

Comment: I'm confused why this was downvoted as it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In My case  /:id route setup is located within the callback of my router.route('/').get route. I move them to the same scope as my other route setup and it works as expected.